# Execute some php when contact form 7 is submitted

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I'm trying to send an SMS to the user's mobile when the contact form 7 is successfully submitted, For that, I need to know How can I execute PHP code after form submission. I'll also make use of the values entered by the user.

I know the question is previously answered but that solution is not working in my case.
I added the following code to my `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'process_contact_form_data' );
function process_contact_form_data( $contact_data ){

var_dump($contact_data->posted_data);
$name = $contact_data->posted_data["your-name"];
$email = $contact_data->posted_data["your-email"];

echo $name ;
echo $email;                
}
```

but after adding the code the form keeps on loading after submission and nothing happens not even the data is submitted

Here is my SMS API

```
$parampro['uname'] = "XXXXXX";
$parampro['password'] = "XXXXXX";
$parampro['sender'] = "XXXXXX";
$parampro['receiver'] = $to;     
$parampro['route'] = "XX";
$parampro['msgtype'] = "1";
$parampro['sms'] = $msg; 
$sendsmspro = http_build_query($parampro);
$urlpro="http://newsms.designhost.in/index.php/smsapi/httpapi/?".$sendsmspr;
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlpro); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$resultpro = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Form ist submitted via AJAX and you are sending output which breaks the JSON response. Remove the var_dump and echos and the submit should be visibly confirmed.

If you want to add debug code there, use a file to log it or look at your browser's dev tools to see the raw requests and response.

Comment: I removed it, now the form is working but The php code that I want to execute is not executing

Comment: It has to be executing, otherwise having an `echo` in there wouldn't mess with the output ;). It's probably an unrelated problem. Have you verified that the code you're using to send the SMS works without CF7 and that you're using the correct field provided by the client? Maybe add the code you're using to the question (remove any API keys before you do)?

Comment: Yes, It works fine when I separate it From CF7. Let me make some changes in question to show you that SMS code

Comment: And what is the response from that API?

Comment: This API is provided by my service provider. if the message is successfully sent then $resultpro stores "Message successfully sent" else it stores the error message

Comment: Well, what does it contain in your case when it does not work? Log it to a file, maybe you're not extracting the target number correctly from the form or something similar.

Comment: Then let me know how can I extract the target number, It is a input field in CF7. Currently, I'm using "$to = $contact_data->posted_data["mobile"];" to extract the number

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know what the field name is etc pp. Just open a log file and print `var_export($contact_data->posted_data, true)` into it to see what data is transmitted.

Comment: can I do this by simply putting the function in error_log(). like this `error_log(var_export($contact_data->posted_data, true));`

Comment: If you have access to your error log and it's properly configured, probably, yes. Just give it a try.